# How do you bind a slider to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a bunch of time series data, and I'd like to create a slider to update my graph in D3. I have made various sliders to get practice, however, none bind with my variable, or stop my program completely. I am trying to implement the one [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972). The tiny bit of code I have for this now, is:

```
    <input type = "range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" onChange="something"/>
    <script> 
        var ARRAY_INDEX = 0; // I want the slider to update this variable
    </script>
```

ARRAY_INDEX chooses a particular index in an array of JSON elements to use. I would like to be able to change this value without having to go back into my code and changing the number myself.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/0366t0fs/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an `id` to your slider:

```
<input type = "range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" id="slider"/>
```

The script that uses the `id` to select the slider element:

```
var ARRAY_INDEX = 0; // You better declare this var outside the event handler function if you want to use it else where

$("#slider").on("change",function(){
    ARRAY_INDEX = $(this).val();
    console.log(ARRAY_INDEX)
});
```

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/kjantzer/pen/pbpRxy)

Like **dandavis** says in comments below, you could also use `input` event instead of `change`.
It depends if you want your variable to be updated on cursor move (*real time* value) or only when cursor is "released" (final value).

Comment: @Kevin Jantzer: Thanks for the demo ;)

Comment: `$("#slider").on("input"`... is slightly better UX